# want to print a line and next when match found-python

Tags: python

I have a variable called `message`.

that variable has value like below:

```
:1A:name
:1B:Address
:1C:phone
:2A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:2B:/INSTITUTION
```

from above variable I want to take only  `:2A:` field contains value
which means I wants only below two line

```
:2A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
```

I tried with

```
lines = message.readlines()
for index,line in enumerate(lines):
if :2A: in line:
print lines [index+2]
```

which is not working.

Comment: Edit the question to explain "not working". Error messages?

Comment: Is your `message` variable a string? `readlines()` is a method of file objects.

Comment: Why `TEST VALUE` is expected in the output ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I  have an xml file where I stored these two values /256789422254
TEST VALUE . if either one is available in that xml my conditions match, so that I want to take that two value and stored to another variable.

Comment: @jjj yes message variable is a string

Comment: After taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you will even have some rewards), please edit the question providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, take care about the indentation as your current code isn't well indented.

Comment: Please update with the error you are getting/what's wrong. If you are open to regex, you can use something [like that](https://regex101.com/r/a2DAI1/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = '''
:1A:name
:1B:Address
:1C:phone
:2A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:2B:/INSTITUTION
'''
x, y = s[s.index(':2A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]
x = x.split(':')[2]
print(x, y)
```

**Output:**

```
/256789422254 TEST VALUE
```

Comment: thank you, able to get expected value :) but just want to change this logic s.index(":2B:")] .. because after  :2A: tag not always :2B:  , it can also be :2C: or some thing. So just I want only two line in :2A: tag

Comment: @MansoorIlahi does it always starts with `2` after `:2A:`

Comment: no that's dynamic value

Comment: Thank you  @komatiraju032  hope B='\n'.join(s[s.index(':2A:') - 1 :].strip().split("\n")[:2]) will work??

Comment: also want to store 256789422254 and TEST VALUE in two separate variable. please help on that too.

Comment: Thank you once again :) In output I don't want :2A: I want output like X=/256789422254 and Y= TEST VALUE

Comment: x = x.split(':')[2] is correct or x = x.split(":")[2]  getting uncaught exception

Comment: @MansoorIlahi both are same except quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
message=""":1A:name
:1B:Address
:1C:phone
:2A:/256789422254
TEST VALUE
:2B:/INSTITUTION"""

def solver(lines):
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.find(':2A:') == 0:
            x = i
        if line.find(':2B:') == 0:
            y = i
            break
    return lines[x:min(x + 2, y)]

solver(message.split('\n'))

#Output [':2A:/256789422254', 'TEST VALUE']
```

The solution works by finding the index of ':2A' in the array of lines. It also finds the position of ':2B' in the array. Then it merely returns a slice of the lines in between.